# Is there a way in SQLAlchemy to create polymorphic vertical values using info from more than one foreign table?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, polymorphism

I've attempted to utilize the [polymorphic vertical attribute mapping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/_modules/examples/vertical/dictlike-polymorphic.html) approach from the SQLAlchemy documentation to store custom fields, their types, and their values. But, in my situation this involves three tables instead of the typical two tables when working with polymorphic tables and attributes.

The 4 models that matter:

1. `Reporter`: The main entity that everything is ultimately related back to. It has a relationship called `extra_parameters`, which leads to the `ReporterParameter` model.
2. `ReporterParameter`: The model that contains all custom parameters, plus their metadata (such as `is_required` and `help_text`) that is utilized on the frontend when rendering form fields. It has a relationship called `values`, which leads to the `ParameterValue` model.
3. `ParameterValue`: The model that contains a reference to the `entity_type`, a value is one of the `*_value` fields, and `entity_id` (which is the polymorphic value that combined with `entity_type` tells us which table and record in that table the value is associated with.
4. `Account`, `Report`, `Job`: The example models that demonstrate why I need the polymorphism. I want to be able to utilize vertical attribute mapping and be able to interact with those vertical attribute that are associated with the specific record just like I would with any other columns in the table.

I think my problem lies within the usage of `attribute_mapped_collection`, since the discriminator name is not directly accessible from the `ParameterValue` model, but requires accessing that model's `.parameter` relationship to get the actual name and type info for the parameter. The `value` is directly accessible from the `ParameterValue` with the help of the `PolymorphicVerticalProperty`.

Another curveball is the fact that the foreign key needs to be coerced to a string since there is at least one table that uses a hexed uuid string as the primary key, while the rest of the tables use traditional integers. You can see my attempt at applying a `primaryjoin` on the `Account` model that tries filtering the relationship's results, so that only `ParameterValues` with `entity_type='account'` would be returned before filtering by `Account.id`.

**Question:** What am I doing wrong? How can I re-structure my models to make this work?

I'm a bit stumped with how to get this approach working, but below is my code, along with some comments and desired behavior at the very end of it.

**Fully-contained code:**

```py
"""pip install
Flask==2.0.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
SQLAlchemy==1.4.28
python-slugify==5.0.2
"""
from sqlalchemy import String, literal_column, event, null, case, cast
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import MutableList
from sqlalchemy.orm.collections import attribute_mapped_collection
from sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces import PropComparator
from sqlalchemy import inspect

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from slugify import slugify  # noqa

from datetime import datetime
from uuid import uuid4

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update({
    "SECRET_KEY": "NOTASECRET",
    "SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI": "sqlite:///:memory:",
    "SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS": False
})
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class PolymorphicVerticalProperty(object):
    """A key/value pair with polymorphic value storage.

    The class which is mapped should indicate typing information
    within the "info" dictionary of mapped Column objects; see
    the AnimalFact mapping below for an example.

    @DynamicAttrs
    """

    def __init__(self, key, value=None):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value

    @hybrid_property
    def value(self):
        fieldname, discriminator = self.type_map[self.type]
        if fieldname is None:
            return None
        else:
            return getattr(self, fieldname)

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        py_type = type(value)
        fieldname, discriminator = self.type_map[py_type]

        self.type = discriminator
        if fieldname is not None:
            setattr(self, fieldname, value)

    @value.deleter
    def value(self):
        self._set_value(None)

    @value.comparator
    class value(PropComparator):
        """A comparator for .value, builds a polymorphic comparison
        via CASE."""

        def __init__(self, cls):
            self.cls = cls

        def _case(self):
            pairs = set(self.cls.type_map.values())
            whens = [
                (
                    literal_column("'%s'" % discriminator),
                    cast(getattr(self.cls, attribute), String),
                )
                for attribute, discriminator in pairs
                if attribute is not None
            ]
            return case(whens, value=self.cls.type, else_=null())

        def __eq__(self, other):
            return self._case() == cast(other, String)

        def __ne__(self, other):
            return self._case() != cast(other, String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<%s %r=%r>" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.key, self.value)


@event.listens_for(PolymorphicVerticalProperty, "mapper_configured", propagate=True)
def on_new_class(mapper, cls_):
    """Look for Column objects with type info in them, and work upa lookup table."""

    info_dict = dict()
    info_dict[type(None)] = (None, "none")
    info_dict["none"] = (None, "none")

    for k in mapper.c.keys():
        col = mapper.c[k]
        if "type" in col.info:
            python_type, discriminator = col.info["type"]
            info_dict[python_type] = (k, discriminator)
            info_dict[discriminator] = (k, discriminator)
    cls_.type_map = info_dict


class Reporter(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "reporter"
    # region internally-used fields
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    module = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    klass = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
    # endregion
    # region meta fields
    data_source = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    display_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    # endregion
    # region behaviors
    skip_normalization = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    skip_archival = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    # endregion
    # region otp fields
    requires_otp = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    otp_sender = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    otp_message_regex = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    # endregion
    # region google storage fields
    use_gs = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    gs_bucket_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    gs_folder_path = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    # endregion
    # region google bigquery fields
    use_bq = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    # bq_project = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)  # future feature
    bq_dataset = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    bq_table = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    bq_columns = db.Column(MutableList.as_mutable(db.JSON), nullable=False, default=list())
    bq_ingestion_action = db.Column(
        db.Enum("WRITE_TRUNCATE", "WRITE_APPEND", name="bq_ingestion_action_enum"),
        nullable=False,
        default="WRITE_APPEND"
    )
    # endregion
    # region relationships
    extra_parameters = db.relationship("ReporterParameter", backref="reporter", lazy="dynamic", cascade="all, delete")
    accounts = db.relationship("Account", backref="reporter", cascade="all, delete")
    reports = db.relationship("Report", backref="reporter", cascade="all, delete")
    jobs = db.relationship("Job", backref="reporter", cascade="all, delete")
    # endregion

    @staticmethod
    def slugify(target, new_value, old_value, initiator):
        if new_value and (not target.slug or new_value != old_value):
            new_slug = slugify(new_value, lowercase=True, max_length=20, word_boundary=True, save_order=True)
            target.slug = new_slug


event.listen(Reporter.display_name, "set", Reporter.slugify, retval=False)


class ReporterParameter(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "reporter_parameter"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    reporter_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("reporter.id"), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False)
    type = db.Column(
        db.Enum("str", "int", "bool", "list", name="parameter_type_enum"),
        nullable=False,
        default="str"
    )
    display_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True, default=None)
    is_required = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    help_text = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True, default=None)
    # region relationships
    values = db.relationship("ParameterValue", backref="parameter")
    # endregion


class ParameterValue(PolymorphicVerticalProperty, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "parameter_value"
    __table_args__ = (
        db.UniqueConstraint("entity_type", "entity_id", "parameter_id", name="entity_parameter_uc"),
    )
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parameter_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("reporter_parameter.id"), nullable=False)
    entity_id = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    entity_type = db.Column(
        db.Enum("reporter", "account", "report", "job", name="entity_type_enum"),
        nullable=False
    )
    str_value = db.Column(db.String(100), info={"type": (str, "string")}, nullable=True)
    int_value = db.Column(db.Integer, info={"type": (int, "integer")}, nullable=True)
    bool_value = db.Column(db.Boolean, info={"type": (bool, "boolean")}, nullable=True)
    list_value = db.Column(MutableList.as_mutable(db.JSON), info={"type": (list, "json")}, nullable=True)


accounts_reports = db.Table(
    "accounts_reports",
    db.Column("account_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("account.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True),
    db.Column("report_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("report.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True)
)


class Account(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "account"
    __table_args__ = (
        db.UniqueConstraint("reporter_id", "username", name="reporter_account_uc"),
    )
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    reporter_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("reporter.id"), nullable=False)
    client_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    otp_secret = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    # region relationships
    parameters = db.relationship(
        "ParameterValue",
        # I attempted to add a primaryjoin to restrict values to only those that apply to "account" entity_type
        # primaryjoin=(
        #     "and_("
        #     "cast(Account.id, String)==foreign(ParameterValue.entity_id), "
        #     "ParameterValue.entity_type=='account'"
        #     ")"
        # ),
        collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection("parameter.name")  # I'm pretty sure I can't use dot notation here
    )
    reports = db.relationship("Report", secondary=accounts_reports, back_populates="accounts")
    # endregion


class Report(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "report"
    __table_args__ = (
        db.UniqueConstraint("reporter_id", "title", name="report_title_uc"),
    )
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    reporter_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("reporter.id"), nullable=False)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    data_source = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    interval = db.Column(
        db.Enum("adhoc", "daily", "weekly", "monthly", "every x weeks", name="report_interval_enum"),
        nullable=False,
        default="adhoc"
    )
    # region relationships
    parameters = db.relationship("ParameterValue", collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection("parameter.name"))
    accounts = db.relationship("Account", secondary=accounts_reports, back_populates="reports")
    jobs = db.relationship("Job", backref="report", cascade="all, delete")
    # endregion


class Job(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "job"
    id = db.Column(db.String(32), primary_key=True, default=lambda: uuid4().hex)
    reporter_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("reporter.id"), nullable=False)
    report_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("report.id"), nullable=False)
    type = db.Column(db.Enum("cron", "adhoc", name="job_type_enum"), nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(
        db.Enum("scheduled", "submitted", "running", "done", "error", name="job_status_enum"),
        nullable=False
    )
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    last_modified_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow, onupdate=datetime.utcnow)
    apscheduler_job_id = db.Column(db.Unicode(191, _warn_on_bytestring=False), db.ForeignKey("apscheduler_jobs.id"))
    # region relationships
    parameters = db.relationship("ParameterValue", collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection("parameter.name"))
    # endregion


class APSchedulerConfig(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "apscheduler_jobs"
    id = db.Column(db.Unicode(191, _warn_on_bytestring=False), primary_key=True)
    next_run_time = db.Column(db.Float(25), index=True)
    job_state = db.Column(db.LargeBinary, nullable=False)
    jobs = db.relationship("Job", backref="apscheduler_job")


@app.before_first_request
def startup():
    db.create_all()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # expected behavior
    app.app_context().push()  # for demonstration purposes I'm ignoring flask context
    db.create_all()
    db.session.add(
        Reporter(
            module="a",
            klass="b",
            display_name="c",
            extra_parameters=[
                ReporterParameter(name="d", type="str", display_name="Dee"),
                ReporterParameter(name="e", type="int", display_name="Eey"),
                ReporterParameter(name="f", type="bool", display_name="Eff"),
                ReporterParameter(name="g", type="list", display_name="Gee")
            ],
            accounts=[
                Account(parameters=dict(d="h", e=1, f=False, g=["h", "i", "j"])),
                # or is it possible without having to specify "parameters"?
                Account(d="h", e=1, f=False, g=["h", "i", "j"])
            ]
        )
    )
    db.session.commit()
    act = Account.query.first()
    # act should have the added ReporterParameter columns in addition to those explicitly defined in the model
    assert act.keys() == ("reporter_id", "client_name", "username", "password", "otp_secret", "d", "e", "f", "g")
    # with each record having their specific values from ParameterValue
    print(act.d)  # "h"
    print(act.e)  # 1
    print(act.f)  # False
    print(act.g)  # ["h", "i", "j"]
```